# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

espero se encuentren bien. Actualmente estoy intentando correr un programa, pero me salta el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

según muestra, el error viene de esta línea:

```
seguirRevisando = pd.read_excel(rutaHistoricaSeguirRevisando, columns=columnNames)
```

la ruta historica seguir revisando es la siguiente:

```
rutaHistoricaSeguirRevisando = os.path.join(rutaHomeVariable, "seguir_pendiente_historica.xlsx")
```

alguien sabe a que se debe el error? he intentado de todas las formas y no encuentro solución

Comment: El error que te envia es por que no reconoce ese parámetro que le mandas, y segun la documentación, no lo tiene [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Puedes leer la excel sin ese parámetro, y después hacer `seguirRevisando.columns = columnNames`

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por los comentarios. Lo resolví cambiando el columns por usecols. Funciona bien